# Range slider - How to add vertical lines on track?

Tags: html, css, slider

I'm trying to add vertical, intersecting lines on the track of a range slider.

I'm using CSS (repeating-linear-gradient) to create the vertical lines but of course, they are not aligned with the "step" or wherever the thumb gets moved to. The step is currently set to "10".

Also, it would be great if this is responsive.

Thanks ahead for your help! Here is my code:

```css
.slider-container {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient( to right, #fff, #fff 3%, #ccc 3%, #ccc 6%);
  background-position: center;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <input type="range" min="-50" max="50" step="10" value="0" class="slider">
</div>
```

Comment: I have done this before when you know the max number of range inputs for the field.  Would that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

This was my solution for a similar project.  You will need some JS to calculate the percentages in both the HTML and CSS.  You can use images or something else for the ticks.

https://jsfiddle.net/jennifergoncalves/qknygt8v/34/

```css
/* Sliders */
.slider-container {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
.slider-container .slider {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
 background: #eee;
 height: 25px;
 margin: 0;
 outline: none;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

/* Sliders - IE */
.slider-container input[type=range]::-ms-track {
 background: #eee;
 border-color: transparent;
 border-width: 6px 0;
 color: transparent;
 height: 25px;
 width: 100%;
}
.slider-container input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
 background: #eee;
}

/* The slider handle (use -webkit- (Chrome, Opera, Safari, Edge) and -moz- (Firefox) to override default look) */ 
.slider-container .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
 background: red;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 25px;
 width: 25%; /* use JS to calculate */
}
.slider-container .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
 background: red;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 25px;
 width: 25%; /* use JS to calculate */
}
.slider-container  input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
 background: red;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 25px;
 width: 40px; /* Set a specific slider handle width, cannot use percents */
}
/* Sliders - thumbs */
.slider-container .slider.slider-option1::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 width: 100%;
}
.slider-container .slider.slider-option1::-moz-range-thumb {
 width: 100%;
}
.slider-container .slider.slider-option2::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 width: 50%;
}
.slider-container .slider.slider-option2::-moz-range-thumb {
 width: 50%;
}
.slider-container .slider.slider-option3::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 width: 33.3%;
}
.slider-container .slider.slider-option3::-moz-range-thumb {
 width: 33.3%;
}
.slider-container .slider.slider-option4::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 width: 25%;
}
.slider-container .slider.slider-option4::-moz-range-thumb {
 width: 25%;
}
.slider-container .slider.slider-option5::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 width: 20%;
}
.slider-container .slider.slider-option5::-moz-range-thumb {
 width: 20%;
}
.slider-container .slider.slider-option6::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 width: 16.6%;
}
.slider-container .slider.slider-option6::-moz-range-thumb {
 width: 16.6%;
}
.slider-container .slider.slider-option7::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 width: 14.2%;
}
.slider-container .slider.slider-option7::-moz-range-thumb {
 width: 14.2%;
}
.slider-container .slider.slider-option8::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 width: 12.5%;
}
.slider-container .slider.slider-option8::-moz-range-thumb {
 width: 12.5%;
}
.slider-container .slider.slider-option9::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 width: 11.1%;
}
.slider-container .slider.slider-option9::-moz-range-thumb {
 width: 11.1%;
}
.slider-container .slider.slider-option10::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 width: 10%;
}
.slider-container .slider.slider-option10::-moz-range-thumb {
 width: 10%;
}

/* Sliders - ticks */
.slider-container ul.slider-ticks {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.slider-container ul.slider-ticks {
 height: 10px;
 position: relative;
 top: -5px;
}
.slider-container ul.slider-ticks li {
 color: #aaa;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 10px;
 line-height: 10px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: top; 
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container"><input type="range" min="1" max="4" value="3" class="slider gh-slider-option4" id="test">
  <ul class="slider-ticks"><li style="width: 25%">l</li><li style="width: 25%">l</li><li style="width: 25%">l</li><li style="width: 25%">l</li></ul>
</div>
```